# Better memory manipulation GoLang

Tags: go

I have an XML file where all its content comes in a single line. I want to format this file, and to do this, I'm using [xmlfmt](https://github.com/go-xmlfmt/xmlfmt).

The code works very well for small files, however, my file is around 700MB and whenever I run the code I get the error "out of memory".

What can I do to use less memory?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-xmlfmt/xmlfmt"
)

func main() {
    file, _ := os.Open("file.xml")
    defer file.Close()
    newFile, _ := os.Create("newFile.xml")
    defer newFile.Close()
    content, _ := io.ReadAll(file)
    convertedContent := string(content)
    result := []byte(xmlfmt.FormatXML(convertedContent, "", "  "))
    newFile.Write(result)
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I've voted to close this because it seems quite a vague question -- "what can I do to use less memory" is about the same as "how can I lose more weight" .... could you please help to refine the question, maybe?

Comment: On a related note... I think many modern systems should have more than 700MB available, even on bad days - could you reliably reproduce this issue with fewer background programs running, etc?

Comment: Use xml/Decoder to decode it, and format it, and output it. That way you can stream and format without using much memory,.

Comment: Write a formatter that streams from the input to the output using the streaming features in the standard encoding/xml package.

Comment: You're making three copies of the file in memory (one in`content`, one in `convertedContent`, and one in `result`). Why do you think you need all of those?

Comment: Use https://go.dev/play/p/VMTn4mwZMkY to remove two copy operations.

Comment: xmlfmt is not designed for a streaming operation so the best you can do is while using xmlfmt is Cerise's solution (or look for some  XML processor that doesn't need the whole document).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmlfmt does not offer a streaming interface. Also, it uses regular expressions to do its work, which is a terrible idea simply because XML is not a regular language<sup>1</sup>. I would strongly advise against using this library.

Luckily, Go's standard library is perfectly capable of indenting XML and it can do so in a streaming fashion:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "errors"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var xmlStr = `<foo><bar /></foo>`

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(xmlStr) // replace with os.Open

    dec := xml.NewDecoder(r)

    var w io.Writer = os.Stdout // replace with newFile
    enc := xml.NewEncoder(w)
    enc.Indent("", "  ")

    for {
        t, err := dec.Token()
        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            break
        }

        enc.EncodeToken(t)
    }

    if err := enc.Close(); err != nil {
        // TODO: delete newFile
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    w.Write([]byte{'\n'})
}

// Output:
// <foo>
//   <bar></bar>
// </foo>
```

Since Encoder.Close can return an error after the XML document has been partially written, you should write to a temporary file and then rename the file if no errors ocurred.

---

1. See also [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/1732454#1732454)

Comment: XML and (X)HTML aren't the same thing. XML is required to be well-formed to be valid, just like JSON. It's still not efficient to parse it with RegExp, but it's certainly possible, unlike trying to parse HTML with regex.

Comment: The code works great, but the namespace of my second tag is being replicated to the others. I wish this didn't happen. Is there any way to do this?